# Where can i find instructions on how to install a NXT wallet app on my Ubuntu server so I can access it via the web?

Tags: nxt

I want to install a NXT wallet client/server on my ubuntu server so i can access it from my website. Where can i find instructions for this? And is there a way to change the port # for nxt? currently it 7876.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure Java 7 is installed on your Ubuntu Server

   - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre nano zip`
2. Download the latest NRS release and verify the hash sum, example:

   - `wget https://bitbucket.org/JeanLucPicard/nxt/downloads/nxt-client-1.1.6.zip`
   - `sha256sum nxt-client-1.1.6.zip`
   - Compare with valid hash found on https://nxtforum.org/nrs-releases/nrs-v1-1-6/
   - `unzip nxt-client-1.1.6.zip`
   - `cd nxt`
3. To change NXT's properties (such as port), edit *nxt-default.properties*

   - `nano conf/nxt-default.properties`  (CTRL+O to save, CTRL+X to quit.)
4. Launch NXT

   - `./run.sh` and access via browser, ip:xxxx

Comment: can i edit html template / css files? i want to add in my own on screen keyboard to increase security.

Comment: also how would you update this when a newer version comes out.

Comment: You may edit any file as you wish. When a newer version comes out, simply do the same again but replace 1.1.6 with the latest version.  There's also a ["Nxt Kit"](https://github.com/nxt-ext/nxt-kit), which enables an easy way to deploy/update NXT on any number of your VPS or Dedicated Servers.